# Python requests response Json does not convert to dictionary

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, dictionary, python-requests

I get a nested Json as request response, trying to exact the `name` field. However after converting it to Json, what supposed to be a dictionary turned to a string. Could you please help pointing out what I did wrong and how to handle this? Many thanks.

sample result from print `response.json()`:

```
{'subject': 'order', 'id':20, 'info':{"result":"record","name":"orderrecords", "items":[{"name":"apple","type":"food"},{"name":"orange","type":"food"}]}
```

I tried with :

```
response= requests.get("url")
info= response.json()
print (type(info["items"]) #it is str here
```

What I am looking to achieve is having a dictionary with value of "name", the one with in items, as keys and the "type" as value. Like {"apple":"food", "orange": "food"}

Comment: u provided invalid json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `json` object returned is not a valid one as `json` should have `"` and not `'`.

You can use `replace()` to replace `'` with `"` and then convert to `json` object:

```
import json
data = '''{'subject': 'order', 'id':20, 'info':{"result":"record","name":"orderrecords", "items":[{"name":"apple","type":"food"},{"name":"orange","type":"food"}]}}''' # there is also a missing } in the end
data = data.replace("'", '"')
data_json = json.loads(data)
res = {elt["name"] : elt["type"] for elt in data_json["info"]["items"]}
print(res)
```

Output:

```
{'apple': 'food', 'orange': 'food'}
```

Note: This will also replace any single quotes which are present as part of data if any.

Answer (score 0):

When the json result is printed on console expected to have result in '. But the object/variable(info) might have the json format.

First of all the result obtained has syntax issue. please add curly braces:

```
info = {'subject': 'order', 'id':20, 'info':{"result":"record","name":"orderrecords", "items":[{"name":"apple","type":"food"},{"name":"orange","type":"food"}]}}

Even if the object is dictionary:

print(info["info"]["items"][0])
print(info["info"]["items"][1])
```

if the result is in json then please import json & load as above suggestion